# Pattern for retrieving data exposed by a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, design-patterns

Are there any suggested patterns for exposing data via a WCF service? I am using netTCP so WCF data services are out. I have a couple of methods that would just normally be overloads but since WCF doesn't support it I have to keep coming up with imaginative names or move methods around between the various service contracts. For example

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFooService
{

    [ServiceOperation]
    List<Foo> GetFoos ();

    [ServiceOperation]
    List<Foo> GetFoosByBar (int barId);

    [ServiceOperation]
    List<Foo> GetFoosByBarByBaz (int barId, int baz);

    [ServiceOperation]
    List<Foo> GetFoosByBarByBazByQux (int bardId, int baz, string qux);
}
```

I would much rather have one GetFoos method. Would the practise be to create something like this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFooService
{
    [ServiceOperation]
    List<Foo> GetFoos(FooRequest request);
}


[DataContract]
public FooRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public int? BarId {get;set}

    [DataMemeber]
    public int? BazId {get;set}

    [DataMember]
    public string Qux {get;set}
}
```

Comment: second option is good

Answer (score 1):

You only have two options.

1. Create unique names just like you have
2. Pass in a 'criteria' object that contains data members with the various criteria possiblities. This allows you to use a single web service with an expandable number of criteria inputs. An additional benefit is that you can add new criteria variables without changing the signature of the service. The only downfall to this approach is that you have to do a lot more work validating input (e.g. did user specify multiple criteria variables when you expected one, etc.).

No right answer - it is subjective based on what you prefer and how you want your api to look.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with the first option. WCF works in terms of messages so it's strongly recommended to design message based contracts. This is much more convinient from flexibility and versionability perspective. A couple of real life examples:

- Mapping. There are many nice mapping tools. Personally I found them really helpful as well. You might want to create a Query object which is passed to your repository to query data. It's much more easier to configure mapping from a DTO to your Query object than mapping a bunch of method arguments.
- Coding. You might want to decorate the service method arguments with validation, logging, etc. attributes. Just imaging what your method definition will look like with all that stuff if you go with procedural way.
- Quite often besides other data you have to return ErrorCode and ErrorMessage if applicable. This is pretty easy to do if you have a base class. ResponseBase which contains those properties and all response classes inherit this one.
- and there are many others.

So the ideal contract definition will look like that:

```
MethodResponse GetData(MethodRequest request);
```

In most cases there are also base classes for response and request objects. This eases things when dealing with the objects in the WCF pipline.

Please note there are basicly two means two design message based contracts in WCF. DataContract and [MessageContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). With MessageContract you have even more control over your message.

Finally if you don't trust me just take a look at how most wide spread web services are designed: Amazon, Facebook, Azure, etc. They are all message based!

A good article to read up on the topic - [Advantages of message based web services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services).

Hope it helps!